# Random integers from a function always return the same number - why?

Tags: c++, random, stl

I'm currently learning C++ and have a question about the random_device.

I'm trying to simulate the monty hall problem. For this I need random integers to pick random doors. Therefore I tried making a function that returns random integers for this purpose.

```
int guessGetRandomIndex() {
    std::random_device rd; // obtain a random number from hardware
    std::mt19937 eng(rd()); // seed the generator
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> distr(0, 2);
    return distr(eng);
```

However when I try to get random integers in main() I keep getting same numbers.

```
    vector<int> v = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
for (auto & j : v){
    int random = guessGetRandomIndex();
    std::cout << random << ' ';
}    
 Output: 1 1 1 1 1 etc.
```

However when I put the random device in the main loop and do the same there I manage to get random integers.

```
    std::random_device rd; // obtain a random number from hardware
std::mt19937 eng(rd()); // seed the generator
std::uniform_int_distribution<> distr(0, 2); // define the range
vector<int> v = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
for (auto & j : v){

    std::cout << distr(eng) << ' ';
}   

 Output: 1 2 1 2 0 1
```

Why is that? I'm simply trying to encapsulate the random device. I thought it would generate new random number each time the function is called similiar to Pythons random.randint but I reckon there is something else going on in C++.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're not encapsulating *a* random device with your function; you're encapsulating N random devices and prngs, where N is the number of executions being invoked. Make both of those (the `random_device` and the `mt19937`), *static*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're creating a new `std::random_device` and `std::mt19937` generator every time you call `guessGetRandomIndex`. Mark them as `static` or pass them to the function via reference to avoid re-instantiating them:

```
int guessGetRandomIndex() {
    static std::random_device rd; // obtain a random number from hardware
    static std::mt19937 eng(rd()); // seed the generator
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> distr(0, 2);
    return distr(eng);
}
```

In order to generate pseudorandom numbers, the generators provided by the standard library contain an internal status that varies every time they generate a value. If you keep re-instantiating a generator, the internal state will always match its initial one, thus always generating the same number.

Comment: It would also be helpful if you explained _why_ instantiating the RNG each time is the cause of the problem as well.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifictation. You guys are awesome! 
However simply using return rand() % 2; in the function solved the problem, how come? I guess the rand() function has static random_device  and mt19937 already built in if I'm not mistaken?

Comment: `rand()` has nothing to do with the Standard Library `<random>` module - it is a C function with different seeding rules. Look at [its documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand). Its use is discouraged as it produces low-quality PRNG numbers and it's not idiomatic modern C++.

Comment: Regarding `rand()` - You should watch this: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful

Comment: Aren't the new random value generated by the std::random_device suppose to be generated with a high entropy? Thus not just returning the same value for every new instance of a std::random_device?

Comment: @Jonas sadly no. `std::random_device` can be implemented in such a way that you get the same sequence of random numbers every time. [The caveat posted to cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device) is as follows: "std::random_device may be implemented in terms of an implementation-defined pseudo-random number engine if a non-deterministic source (e.g. a hardware device) is not available to the implementation. In this case each std::random_device object may generate the same number sequence."

Comment: @user4581301 that is just sad. std::random_device should rely on a OS dependent high entropy generator. Now I'm just left with trust issues...

Comment: @Jonas that is what an implementation could do. If you have a high reliability RNG, use it, but the standard has to leave open the possibility that an implementation could be running bare metal or have no trusted third-party support. Reading from **[rand.device]** in a recent draft of the standard,  "If implementation limitations prevent generating non-deterministic random numbers, the implementation may employ a random number engine." which leads to the problem of how does one seed the seeder?

Answer (score 3):

While it's not guaranteed to give identical results every time, the way you're trying to do things is definitely sub-optimal (bordering on just plain wrong). In particular, at least as you've shown the code, you're re-seeding the PRNG every time you ask for another number. What you want to do is seed it once, then use successive numbers without re-seeding.

You can fix this by marking them as `static` in the function, or (usually better) use a class, with those actions carried out in the ctor, and generating a number in a member function:

```
class RandomIndex {
    std::mt19937 eng;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> distr;
public:
    guessGetRandomIndex(int lower, int upper) 
        : eng(std::random_device()())
        , distr(lower, upper)
    {}

    int operator()() { 
         return distr(eng);
    }
};
```

This is a little extra code, but not massively so--and it can have some benefits<sup>1</sup>.

Using this is fairly simple:

```
RandomIndex d(0, 2);

for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    std::cout << d();
```

One result:

```
0 2 1 2 1 2 0 2 1 0
```

One minor side-note: although this particular run doesn't show repetitions of a single number, it does include the sequence `2 1` more than most people tend to expect. In fact, tests have shown that people generally expect a random sequence to contain substantially less repetition (of single numbers or of sequences like shown above) than will happen randomly. For example, most people would glance at a sequence like `0 0 1 1 2 2` and judge it as something that should *never* (or nearly never) happen randomly. In fact, it's just as likely as any other sequence with the same parameters, so if you prevent it from happening, you're *reducing* randomness.

---

<sup>1. For example, a function with statics may include some code to check whether initialization has been done, and do it if and only if it hasn't been done previously.</sup>