# Generate Random Number in 2D Vector C++

Tags: c++, vector, random, printing, floating-point

I am implementing a simple 2D vector class in C++ which initialize a 2D vector with a given size (number of row and column) and whether to randomize the value or not. I also implement the method to print the matrix to the console to see the  result.

I have tried to run the code using GCC 8.3.0 in Windows (MSYS2) with flag "-std=c++17". Here is the code.

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


class Vec2D
{
public:
    Vec2D(int numRows, int numCols, bool isRandom)
    {
        this->numRows = numRows;
        this->numCols = numCols;

        for(int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) 
        {
            std::vector<double> colValues;

            for(int j = 0; j < numCols; j++) 
            {
                double r = isRandom == true ? this->getRand() : 0.00;
                colValues.push_back(r);
            }

            this->values.push_back(colValues);
        }
    }

    double getRand()
    {
        std::random_device rd;
        std::mt19937 gen(rd());
        std::uniform_real_distribution<> dis(0,1);

        return dis(gen);
    }

    void printVec2D()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < this->numRows; i++) 
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < this->numCols; j++)
            {
                std::cout << this->values.at(i).at(j) << "\t";
            }
        std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }
private:
    int numRows;
    int numCols;

    std::vector< std::vector<double> > values;
};

int main()
{
    Vec2D *v = new Vec2D(3,4,true);

    v->printVec2D();
}
```

What I expected is a 2D vector with randomized value when 'isRandom' argument is `true`. Instead, I got vector with values being all the same.
For example. when I run the code in my computer I got this:

```
0.726249        0.726249        0.726249        0.726249
0.726249        0.726249        0.726249        0.726249
0.726249        0.726249        0.726249        0.726249
```

My question is what is wrong with my C++ code? Thank you in advance for the answer.

Comment: OT: What you call _2D vector_, I call a "matrix". A 2D vector would be (for me) a pair of 2 numbers. (Sorry for nitpicking.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Random integers from a function always return the same number - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41489979/random-integers-from-a-function-always-return-the-same-number-why)

Comment: You generate a new random number generator on each call to getRand(), probably resetting the seed (to 0?) each time, so it makes sense you get the same value each time.

Answer (score 1):

I think the generator should not be created each time, make this part member and only call `dis`

```
    std::random_device rd; //Will be used to ***obtain a seed for the random number engine***
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> dis(0,1);
```

and second, make sure you called

`std::srand(std::time(nullptr));`

only once at the beging of the application